# How to remove element (div) based on dependent value

Tags: jquery

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fH3Sc/

Using the given HTML (without modifying it), how can I remove the last instance of each `special-text` div based on a parent or neighboring div's content/attributes?

```
$(".special-text").slice(0, -1).remove();
```

This will keep the last instance of a `special-text` div on the page.

I want to keep the LAST UNIQUE instance of each `special-text` div. In the case that more divs were added to the fiddle, it should ideally only show the LAST UNIQUE instance of each `special-text` div.

**Goal output:** http://jsfiddle.net/JdbTx/

Comment: Can you explain the logic again, why only 3 divs are removed?

Comment: I only want the last UNIQUE `special-text` div to display.

Comment: Include a minimal input/output case in code. Links are nice, but not suitable alone.

Comment: The title change I made sort of gave it away: a dependency has to be established. This can't be done with a single query because a single query cannot (by itself) select on dependent values (AFAIK) with standard jQuery/CSS selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the different text strings and store the corresponding elements in an hash containing arrays.  Then just remove the non-last elements in each array.

```
var texts = {};
$(".special-text").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(!texts.hasOwnProperty(text)) {
       texts[text] = [];
    }
    texts[text].push(this);
});

$.each(texts, function(text, elements) {
    $(elements).not(":last").remove();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fH3Sc/5/) demo

Or [another way](http://jsfiddle.net/fH3Sc/8/), based on Jan's answer that does it in a single run:

```
var keepers = {};
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
$(".special-text").reverse().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text(), include = keepers[text] === true;
    keepers[text] = true;
    return include;
}).remove();
```

Comment: I think I've gotten it down to about as terse as it will get.  I'm saving a lot of `$` invocations and `text` calls.  Bring it :P

Comment: You won by more than I expected. I would think that the reverse operation would be much more expensive. http://jsperf.com/remove-duplicate

Comment: Even after I extended the test sample ~16x, you still win in speed

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, I could see it going either way.  Sometimes even the native functions can be pretty slow because they do a [lot of checking](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.8) that might be skipped over by a naive js implementation.

Comment: Typechecks were not what I was worried about.

Comment: Also note that you can replace jQuery loops with native loops, and avoid the reversing completely. This is still far from optimal :-)

Comment: What *were* you worried about?  It's an in-place reverse so I wouldn't expect too much pain moving items to their new homes, but that's more VM implementation and where my knowledge starts to get fuzzy.  And yes, raw DOM and for-loops would beat up jQuery and take its lunch money.

Comment: So, the improvement is not the reduced loop count (there are just as many, IIUC), but rather the reduced amount of abstraction, IIUC.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var obj = {};
$('.special-text').each(function(i, v){
    obj[$(v).text()] = true;
});

$.each(obj, function(i, v){
    $('.special-text:contains(' + i + ')').not(':last').remove()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fH3Sc/3/)

The step 1 identifies all unique `special-text` values, then we iterate through the list and remove all except the last item matching the special text.

Update: I would recommend the [answer from Jan Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016235/how-to-remove-element-div-based-on-dependent-value/15016368#answer-15016405) as mine has some problems as noted in the comments.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks. If you don't mind, can you give me a basic rundown of the code? The logic is intriguing.

Comment: I'm wondering if my approach is more efficient. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15016405/499214

Comment: The thing about this approach is that it does a substring match. So if you had a div of "Arbok!" and "Go Arbok!" it would produce unusual results.

Comment: Agreed - you do string interpolation. You should escape the string. Otherwise, it's SQL injection revived.

Comment: @Plynx `"Arbok!"`  is bad, but `"],*[id!="xyzzy` is worse

Comment: The selector is expensive and risky, so I'm not sure I'd use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific CSS selector here, but you can do this manually:

```
var keepers = {};

$(".special-text").each(function(){
    keepers[$(this).text()]=this
}).each(function(){
  if(keepers[$(this).text()]!=this){
    $(this).remove()
  }
})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/fH3Sc/4/

The logic is as follows:

1)collect all posts that we want to keep, at most one per its contents, overwriting older entries (meaning that only the last instance of each post will make it to stay on the list)

2)remove all entries that did not stay on that list

Comment: This too is what I needed, thanks. Can you explain a basic rundown of the code?

Comment: This looks more efficient I think, My second loop might be a little constly

Answer (score 0):

These two lines reproduce what you have in your second fiddle.

```
$(".name:contains('Jessie')").slice(0, 2).next('.special-text').remove();
$(".name:contains('Meowth')").first().next('.special-text').remove();
```

As the names `Jessie` and `Meowth` are not unique it is difficult to give a concise answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".post > .name:contains('Jessie')").nextAll(".special-text").remove();
```

[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fH3Sc/1/)

Comment: Once again, this is not what the user wants. Check the fiddle with the desired output.